# Change style of DIV on click and change again on unclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have a div with the ID colormethis and I want to change the style on click and change it again on unclick. As in it gets highlighted on a single click on the radio button and clicking again will unhighlight it. The radio doesn't have to get unselected for now, I just need the behavior on the DIV.  I tried this:

```
function highlightSelected() {
if ($i = 0 || $i = null){
$("#colormethis").css({"background-color":"#CC0000"});
$("#colormethis").css({"color":"#FFFFFF"});
$("#colormethis").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
$i = 1;
}
else if ($i = 1) {
$("#colormethis").css({"background-color":"#FFFFFF"});
$("#colormethis").css({"color":"#000000"});
$("#colormethis").css({"font-weight":"normal"});
$i = 0;
}
};

 <div id="colormethis" style="width:200px;border:1px #CC0000 solid;"><input onclick="highlightSelected()" id="button" type="radio" name="controller" value="random">Content here</div>
```

but it doesn't seem to fire off at all.

What's wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't simply toggling a class be easier?

Comment: Also your $1 = 0 should be $1 === 0 or at least $1 == 0

Comment: @j08691 I knew there should be an easier way to do this, but I thought jQuery worked like PHP. As always I was proven wrong as it obviously doesn't :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FdCm2/)

**CSS**

```
.active {
    background-color: #CC0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $("#colormethis").toggleClass('active');
});
```

Use class active than [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

you could also use mouse up and down if you like.

```
$("#div").mousedown(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
}).mouseup(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Qud9P/